# Consider a simple connected graph with $n$ vertices $(n ≥ 2)$ such that no two vertices of the same degree are connected by a simple path of length 2

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a connected simple graph with $n$ vertices $(n ≥ 2)$ such that no two vertices of the same degree are connected by a simple path of length $2$. Prove that there exists a vertex of degree $1$.

It's not easy even to imagine a graph like this. For example, it could be a path graph with $4$ vertices, but this tells me nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a nonempty finite graph with maximum degree $\Delta(G)=k\ge1$. Choose a vertex $v$ of degree $\deg(v)=k$. The $k$ neighbors of $v$ have $k$ different degrees, which are all in the set $\{1,\dots,k\}$, so every element of that set must be the degree of some neighbor of $v$.